# How can I get this .box class to flow like blog posts? + tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Everything is exactly where I want it except for the `.box` class. I want the left and right margins to be centered while the top margin matches that of the sidebar. That part worked out perfectly fine, however, the boxes overlap. Where on earth did I go wrong?

Here's the CSS:

```
.box {
width: 250px;
margin: -260px auto;
padding: 25px;
border: solid 1px;
word-wrap: break-word;
position:relative;
display:block;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="box">
box content
</div>
```

And now for the tooltip issue... It works fine when I preview the file in a browser but when I uploaded the site, tooltip didn't show up.

You can also see it live here (please use view-source to see the whole code): https://peachie.000webhostapp.com/mobile.html

And don't worry about the "mobile.html" thing, I am nowhere near done with this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The overlapping is caused by negative margin of the second .box element. Make the sidebar element float to left so that you don't have to use negative margin for .box elements.
CSS:

```
#sidebar {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font: italic 9px arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  float: left;
}
.box {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 25px;
  border: solid 1px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

2) Tooltips don't work because the main page is loaded in HTTPS and tooltip scripts referenced in HTTP. Browser doesn't allow HTTP content to be loaded in HTTPS. Use HTTPS src for these:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://static.tumblr.com/iuw14ew/VSQma1786/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>
```